# Magento Multi Store Price Update Script - Mage Eav Model Entity Attribute Exception

Tags: php, magento

We are running Magento with 2 stores, 1 store is retail, the other is wholesale. They share a single catalog, with split pricing between the two stores.

The script I am writing simply takes all of the pricing from the wholesaler site and is supposed to update the current price to the current price reflecting a 10% discount. My script is throwing the following error:

> Total Products: 51937
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' in >/var/www/vhosts/mediagiantdesign.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1353

I have been wrestling with this for a little while. I know magento pretty well and for something trivial like this to stop me in my tracks is a bit aggravating.

Since there is no exception message attached to the stack trace, figuring out what it is has been difficult. It has something to do with setting the storeid on the load. if I take that out, or change it to setWebsiteId it works. However, it updates BOTH sites pricing not just the wholesale side.

Two Additional Notes:

1. Currently both sites prices in the catalog are the same. That is why you see me simply taking the same price from the same product. This script is supposed to apply the initial reduction in the wholesale side of the store.
2. Since I am debugging I have the break condition at the end. I do plan on removing it for a full run - also anyone who finds this post and finds the code useful (after its fixed of course) can remove it to have it run for the full catalog.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

try {
//get the magento product collection for the Vendors website products
$vendorproducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Exception thrown.";
    echo $ex->getTraceAsString();
    echo $ex->getMessage(); //no output - weird.
}

echo "Total Products: " . $vendorproducts->count() . "\r\n";

$count = 0;

foreach($vendorproducts as $product)
{   
    
    $priceupdate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(2)->load($product->getId());

    $retailprice = $priceupdate->getPrice();

    echo $product->getId() . " - " . ($retailprice - ($retailprice *.10)) . "\r\n";

    $priceupdate->setPrice(($retailprice - ($retailprice *.10)));

    $priceupdate->setUrlKey(false);

    $priceupdate->save();

    $count++;

    if ($count > 0)
        break;
 }

 echo $count . " products updated.\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. After some double checking I realized I had specified the wrong StoreID. An invalid store id is a real good way to trip magento up - devil is in the details.

Enjoy the script.